# How should I upgrade to 16.04 now?

Tags: upgrade, 15.10

My download from the distribution upgrade failed because of a problem with the internet. Then I tried `sudo apt-get dist upgrade`, but it still shows 15.10. I also tried `sudo apt-get install wajig`, but there was no change.

I also tried `sudo do-release-update -d` (my update manager is already at the newer version), but it says “no new release found”.

I want to upgrade to 16.04. How can I?

Answer (score 2):

Try these:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo update-manager -d
```

Update manager will open, and click upgrade.

Comment: It says it's up to date

Answer (score 1):

If you're already on Ubuntu 15.10, do:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Comment: Read my question carefully.I said I tried sudo  do-release upgrade.It's not working.It says "No new release found"

Comment: I am not sure if `sudo do-release-update -d` and `sudo do-release-upgrade` are the same.